# How to update all null values to 0 in a dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm dealing on a dataset that has 93 columns and dont want to write query for everything. Let me know if there is any workaround.

used this : UPDATE dummy SET column = 0 WHERE column IS NULL

Need some suggestions where we dont have to explicitly mention each column name. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace `NULL`s with `0`s, then you can update all of them in one statement:

```
UPDATE dummy
    SET col_00 = COALESCE(col_00, 0),
        col_01 = COALESCE(col_01, 0),
        col_02 = COALESCE(col_02, 0),
        . . .;
```

Comment: Still have to mention the column name right? OP wants a solution where he doesn't need to mention the column name

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala . . . I understood that the OP doesn't want to write multiple `update` statements.